# How to stop loading next component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React I want to stop rendering the next component if the current component's input(text fields) are empty. I don't have form or input submitting tags just state and onChange methods.

```
class TextFields extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      studentId: null,
      studentName: null,
      employeeName: null,
      supervisorName: null,
    };
  }

  handleChange = () => event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.setFormPart1Value(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off" >
        <TextField
          required
          id="studentId"
          label="Student ID"
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <TextField
          required
          id="studentName"
          label="Student Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <TextField
          required
          id="employeeName"
          label="Employee Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <TextField
          required
          id="supervisorName"
          label="Supervisor Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          margin="normal"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

So if there is any component methods to stop render or any other ideas without adding form or input submits.
I'm new to React so anyone who can help me..

Answer (score 4):

```js
class TextFields extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      studentId: null,
      studentName: null,
      employeeName: null,
      supervisorName: null,
    };
  }

  handleChange = () => event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.setFormPart1Value(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { studentId, studentName, employeeName} = this.state;

    return (
      <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off" >
        <TextField
          required
          id="studentId"
          label="Student ID"
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          margin="normal"
        />
        {studentId && <TextField
          required
          id="studentName"
          label="Student Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          margin="normal"
        />}
        {studentName && <TextField
          required
          id="employeeName"
          label="Employee Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          margin="normal"
        />}
        {employeeName && <TextField
          required
          id="supervisorName"
          label="Supervisor Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={this.handleChange()}
          margin="normal"
        />}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

you can do something like that,
witch will render only if the previous field has value

Answer (score 0):

Components are supposed to be independent. In this case I suggest that you have a parent component of both interacting parts of the form be the coordinator between them. This can be an existing component to which you assign this new responsibility or a completely new one that has this as its only job.

In either case the parent component will be able to check the state of your text fields and then choose whether the rest of the form is to be rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Have a parent component is it possible to send child component state to the parent component.

Comment: The parents *gives* the state to the child. It can just look at it, no need to communicate it.

Comment: Is it possible to change giving state in child component and send back?

Comment: It probably is but you should never need or do it. When state changes the parent will be re-rendered and will be able to change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        const {studentId, studentName, employeeName} = this.state;
        return (
            <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="studentId"
                    label="Student ID"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={this.handleChange()}
                    margin="normal"
                />
                {studentId &&
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="studentName"
                    label="Student Name"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={this.handleChange()}
                    margin="normal"
                />}
                {studentName &&
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="employeeName"
                    label="Employee Name"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={this.handleChange()}
                    margin="normal"
                />}
                {employeeName &&
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="supervisorName"
                    label="Supervisor Name"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    onChange={this.handleChange()}
                    margin="normal"
                />}
            </form>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need to check

```
if(this.state.studentId && this.state.studentName && this.state.employeeName && this.state.supervisorName) {return <Component/>}
```

If condition is 'true', you can render your component.
Or if you need to pass state of your TextFields Component to child Component via props you need to write
`if(props.studentId && props.studentName && props.employeeName && props.supervisorName) {return <Component/>}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a parent component. It's a stepper taken from Material UI. There is a next button to change the component. All are working fine... I just want to validate the individual components and its text fields. All the inputs are valid n then it have to go to the next component. Is any way to pass the child component to parent component.